# Minimum Description Length for Clustering

Tags: cluster-analysis

I would like to know how to calculate Minimum Description Length (MDL) to evaluate the clustering result.

I was looking at some papers on clustering algorithms, and one of them refers to MDL as a measurement to check if the clusters which are given by K-means follow Gaussian distribution.

According to that paper, MDL is given by:

> MDL(K) = -log[p_y(y/K)] + 1/2 * L * log(n)
>   L = K(1 + n + (n + 1)n / 2) - 1

, where K is the number of the clusters, *n* is the total number of data values, and *y* is an *n* dimensional vector.

I am aware that the above explanation might be insufficient to answer this question, but the above is all the information I have now, and I have no idea how to reproduce the calculation introduced by the paper.

I would appreciate explanations on how to calculate MDL to evaluate clustering results.

Comment: Don't use n for both the number of data points and the number of variables?

Answer (score 0):

MDL calculations always require some assumptions about how to encode the data. And that is where MDL papers are often wrong, because they compare their new encoding to a sub-quality encoding as baseline to get massive gains... Anyway, this value may be legit, but without context and proper definitions it's hard to tell.

When you approximate data with k-means, you have to store:

1. k itself
2. log k bits for each of n points to map points to centers
3. k vectors of d dimensions
4. the deviation of each point from the mean. If you assume small deviations are more frequent (Gaussian), use fewer bits for this, more bits for large deviations